# Almost sure boundedness

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I want to know if there are any well known sufficient conditions for almost sure boundedness of a sequence of (not necessarily independent) non-negative random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$. I say that the sequence $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ of non-negative random variables is bounded almost surely, if the following holds:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{n\geq 1} X_n < \infty\right) = 1.$$
For example, does $\sup_{n\geq 1} \mathbb{E} (X_n) < \infty$ imply that $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded almost surely? Can someone at least provide a counterexample to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I_1,I_2...$ be an arrangement of the intervals $[\frac {i-1} {2^{n}}, \frac i {2^{n}})$ in  a sequence. If $X_n=n$ on $I_n$ and $0$ elsewhere then $sup_nEX_n<\infty$  but $P(\sup_n X_n <\infty)=0$. My basic space is $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false. For instance, if $(X_i)$ is an iid sequence of exponential$(1)$ random variables, then $M_n=\sup_{k\leq n}X_k$ is known (by the [Renyi representation](http://www.math.u-szeged.hu/CsorgoEmlek/talks/Viharos.pdf)) to be exponential with mean $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$, which grows as $\log n$. This is incompatible with a.s. boundedness, since
$$
\mathbb P(M_n>k)=e^{-k/H_n},
$$
which tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$, for every fixed $k$.