# almost sure boundedness counter example

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to work out the following example given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249045/almost-sure-boundedness)

Let $I_1,I_2...$ be an arrangement of the intervals $[\frac {i-1} {2^{n}}, \frac i {2^{n}})$ in  a sequence. If $X_n=n$ on $I_n$ and $0$ elsewhere then $sup_nEX_n<\infty$  but $P(\sup_n X_n <\infty)=0$. My basic space is $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.

$$ A := \{ \sup_n X_n < \infty \} = \{ \omega \in \Omega : \exists M > 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, X_n(\omega) \leq M \}$$

hence the complement is
\begin{align*}
\overline{A} & = \{ \omega \in \Omega: \forall M \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, X_n(\omega) > M \} \\
& = \bigcap_{M \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{ X_n > M \} \\
& = \bigcap_{M \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{n \geq M} \{ X_n > M \} 
\end{align*}

How do i go on from here?

Comment: I think you could conclude this fact without using Borel-Cantelli's. It follows from the construction of such "dancing" sequence of intervals.

Comment: Could you please give me more details? i'm not sure why that is the case. Thanks

Comment: For example, $0 \in [0,1]$. Then $0 \in [\frac{0}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2^n}) := I_{m(n)}$ for all $n$. Then what's the value of $X_{m(n)}(0)$? Notice that when $n \to \infty$, $m(n) \to \infty$. What about other $\omega \in [0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

The example provided there is as follows:

$$
X_{n}(\omega) = \begin{cases} m & \omega \in \left[ \dfrac{k}{2^m},\dfrac{k+1}{2^m}\right]\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
where $m = \lfloor{\log(n)}\rfloor$ and $k=n-2^m$.

To prove $\sup_n X_n = \infty$ almost surely, consider a single point $\omega\in[0,1]$. You can easily verify that $X_n(\omega)$ will go to infinity. Therefore, the set of $\omega$ such that $\sup_n X_n = \infty$ is $[0,1]$. This simple example really does not need more advanced technique like Borel–Cantelli lemma.